# How and by use of which locator should I use to automate main and sub-elements from left navigation in any site?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not getting any locators except full Xpath and also all the left navigation elements are deep inside tags?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to read any articles or watch any free tutorials e.g. [copy selector in chrome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMk7ZLuo6Po)
But what you can do right now is to try to modify your long Xpath by adding unique classNames or id or ...
Of course would be great to see your problem, for example a piece of code with DOM elements from where you trying to get your Xpath